# Git is showing files as changed, even though files are byte-for-byte identical

Tags: git

Git is indicating that a file has changes. However, when I run `git difftool` and open the file in Beyond Compare, it shows the files as binary-identical. Even if I open Beyond Compare in hex-mode, it still shows the files as identical.

I'm running git 2.9.2.windows.1 on Windows 10. I see this issue both when I run git from PowerShell and from the msys git bash prompt.

Has anyone else ever seen this before? Note: I'm not talking about changes in line endings, since line ending differences would clearly be visible in a hex comparison of the files.

Comment: Check the filename in the output of `git ls-files`, verify that the case is matching the real file in your system. For example, if in `git ls-files` you see `someFile` but in your filesystem you have `somefile`, that can cause the behavior you are observing.

Comment: How does Git indicate the changes? Via `git status`, or via `git diff` (not `git difftool`)?

Comment: When I run `git diff`, it shows every line on the file as changed, but, so far as I can tell, there are no content changes. The reason I was using difftool was to view the actual bytes of the file, but those appear to be identical as well.

Comment: @janos I checked the casing using `git ls-files` and the casing of the file names is the same.

Comment: Extend that to running `git ls-files --eol -- <filename>` and post the output here. Even if you ruled out EOL issues the fact that `git diff` shows every line modified clearly indicates EOL issues. Maybe BC is not seeing them due to some conversion happening beforehand.

Comment: Okay, I just got the problem to recur (it's intermittent, and I'm still not sure what the repro steps are). When I run `git ls-files --eol -- <filename>`, I get the following output:

`i/crlf w/crlf attr/text=auto`


It seems like both versions of the file have the same line endings.

Answer (score 2):

That could be a change in the file mode, aka Unix mode bits. Even on Windows (which does not have Unix mode bits) Git does track the file mode which could change e.g. by running `git update-index --chmod=+x <filename>`. You can double-check by running `git status -v` which in this case would display something like

```
$ git status -v
On branch version-defines
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/version-defines'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   circle.yml

diff --git a/circle.yml b/circle.yml
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Comment: I ran `git status -v`, but it just showed pretty much the same output as `git status`. I definitely did not see any file mode changes or any other metadata changes.